# Realm + RaisePropertyChanged not being raised for properties with code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I have a RealmObject with these two properties (IntOption and Option):

```
public enum Option { A, B, C }

public class MyObject : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int IntOption { get; set; }
    public Option Option
    {
        get => (Option)IntOption;
        set
        {
            IntOption = (int)value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, Realm doesn't let you store enum properties, so I have both an enum property and the actual Int value that is being stored. So far, so good.

Now, the weird thing. If I bind these two properties to labels in an XAML file, just like:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Option}" />
 <Label Text="{Binding IntOption}" />
```

And I assign a value to Option in C#:

```
myVariable.Option = Option.A;
```

The label bound to the IntOption property updates with the new value, but the one bound to Option does not.

After much debugging, I think that the key element here is that the element bound to the XAML page, and the one that is being modified by code, are two different variables/object instances, but I don't know what realm is doing so that IntOption actually updates all bindings, but RaisePropertyChanged (which is itself a realm method that should do that), does not.

What should I do so that Option updates all bindings when the property changes, just as it happens with IntOption?

Comment: Hi! That behavior you explained is weird. Try sending the name of the Property explicitly in the `RaisePropertyChanged` method. Something like:

`RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Option));`
`RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IntOption));`

Try this and let us know the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was one of the first things I tried and it didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm still interested in knowing whether there is a simpler/better approach but, for now, I've solved it by overriding the OnPropertyChanged method. As the property internally handled by Realm does raise the PropertyChanged event on all .Net instances of the Realm record, I can check whether that property has been updated, and raise a PropertyChanged event for those that depend on it:

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == nameof(IntOption))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Option));
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with this approach. I would go with it.